# Recording browsing session as a video in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-plugin, screen-recording, browser-addons

I saw a plugin in chrome called as Screencastify which can record browsing session as a video. Is it possible to record a particular div / dom element as a video and save it the disk ?

Comment: I was able to record the browsing session by running a puppeteer headless browser and loaded a plugin to record it as a webm video.